# html присвоение класса элементу через JS

Tags: javascript, html

Странно, но такой код не работает. Что может быть не так?

```js
var a = document.createElement('div');
a.class = 'ab';
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

```css
.ab {
  width:10px;  
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это не работает, потому что нет свойства `class`, есть [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/className)

```js
var a = document.createElement('div');
a.className = 'ab';
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

```css
.ab {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Или же с помощью свойства  **classList**

Comment: @Deonis, да или с помощью него

Comment: @Grundy а для onclick в js тоже какое-то свое название?

Comment: @Юрий, нет, для `onclick` стандартно, плюс события лучше навешивать с помощью [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 4):

На момент создания джаваскрипта ключевые слова не могли использоваться после точки, поэтому вместо `class` и `for` были выбраны `className` и `htmlFor`. Кстати, недопустимость их использования актуальна для IE8.

Ещё можно использовать `classList` - это множество классов элемента, которое также предоставляет некоторые методы взаимодействия.

```js
var a = document.createElement('div');
a.className = 'ab';
document.body.appendChild(a);

var b = document.createElement('div');
b.classList.add('bc');
document.body.appendChild(b);
```

```css
.ab {
  width:10px;  
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.bc {
  width:10px;  
  height: 10px;
  background: green;
}
```